# How can I fix "no such index at level 1" while writing a function in R to fill in the blank values?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that fills empty values with the value "N," but I'm getting the following error. Could someone assist me in resolving this problem?

**Error**

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1

**R Code**

```
library(tidyr)
# create data frame
distance<-c('a','b','c', 'd')
area<-c(11,12,13, "")
type<-c('typea', 'typeb', 'typec', "")

# check data.frame
my.df<-data.frame(distance, area, type)
my.df$area



fillvalues<-function(columName, value){
  my.df[[columName]] <- sub("^$", Value , my.df[[columName]])
  print(my.df)
}

print(fillvalues(area, N))
```

Comment: `my.df["area", my.df$area == ""] <- "N"`? Why are you using regex for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
fillvalues<-function(columnName, value){ 
        my.df %>% 
      mutate({{columnName}} := str_replace({{columnName}}, 
              "^$", rlang::as_string(ensym(value))))}
```

-testing

```
> fillvalues(area, N)
 distance area  type
1        a   11 typea
2        b   12 typeb
3        c   13 typec
4        d    N
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work, make use of quotes when calling your function. Additionally, inside your function it should be `value` instead of `Value`:

```r
fillvalues <- function(columName, value){
  my.df[[columName]] <- sub("^$", value , my.df[[columName]])
  my.df
}

fillvalues("area", "N")
#>   distance area  type
#> 1        a   11 typea
#> 2        b   12 typeb
#> 3        c   13 typec
#> 4        d    N
```